# php-login.net Minimal view user page

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP-LOGIN.NET (non MVC) Minimal 
      I am trying to get make it where a person goes to index.php?id=2 and it will show all data to the user with ID 2 assigned to him/her in the mysql database.

I believe I am to use

```
if(isset($_GET['user_id'])
```

however every witch way i try to use it, it is not working..

here is the index.php

```
require_once("config/db.php");


require_once("classes/Login.php");



$login = new Login();

if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {

include("views/logged_in.php");

} else {

include("views/not_logged_in.php");
```

here is class/login.php

```
class Login
{

private $db_connection = null;

public $errors = array();

public $messages = array();


public function __construct()
{
    // create/read session, absolutely necessary
    session_start();

    // check the possible login actions:
    // if user tried to log out (happen when user clicks logout button)
    if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
        $this->doLogout();
    }

    // login via post data (if user just submitted a login form)
    elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $this->dologinWithPostData();
    }
}



private function dologinWithPostData()
{

    if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {


        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        // change character set to utf8 and check it
        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }

        // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {


            $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);


            $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_password_hash
                    FROM users
                    WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" .   
$user_name . "';";
            $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if this user exists
            if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();








                if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                    // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
                    $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;






                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Wrong password. Try again.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "Database connection problem.";
        }
    }
  }


  public function doLogout()
 {

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    $this->messages[] = "You have been logged out.";

}


  public function isUserLoggedIn()
  {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1)             
{
    return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
}
```

anyhelp will be grate..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We will need to see a lot more code and have more details of the problem.  Do you get error messages?  Any results?

Comment: you are not accessing your problem properly you will take isset($_GET['id'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From everything you give us : There is a big problem : you look for a login when people get in the page `index.php?id=2`

So the var you expect into `$_GET` isn't `user`, but `id`!

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])
```

Comment: yeah i seen that, however I am unable to figure out where to place the code..